# Nib load failure when presenting its view controller

Tags: ios, swift3, xib, xcode8, awakefromnib

I have this function in a class that inherits from `NSObject`:

```
open func showCustomDialogInView(vc: UIViewController) {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: CustomDialogViewController.self)
    let customDialog = CustomDialogViewController(nibName: "CustomDialogViewController", bundle: bundle)
    customDialog.delegate = vc
    customDialog.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
    vc.present(customDialog, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I had this working in one of my iOS projects before updating to `Xcode 8` and `Swift 3` language, but now when I run the app I get a crash when `vc.present(customDialog, animated: true, completion: nil)` line is reached. I get this message in log console:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle /MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'CustomDialogViewController''

I don't understand what it is happening, since `let customDialog = CustomDialogViewController(nibName: "CustomDialogViewController", bundle: bundle)` line doesn't crash and it seems that I get a `CustomDialogViewController` object.

Does somebody could help me with this issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that __customDialog__ gets instantiated?

Comment: You have already indicated "Xcode 8 & swift 3" in the tags, no need to have it in the title as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in this case this error was because for some reason the `xib` file was missing the appropriate target membership.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when you rename files outside of XCode. To solve it you can just remove the files from your project (Right Click - Delete and "Remove Reference").

Then after you can re-import the files in your project and everything will be OK.